# Entity Framework 6 (code first) Add-Migration puts wrong provider to the edmx schema

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a project which is originally used System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0 (MSSQL Compact Edition 4.0) data provider. Then I've made a branch, changed config file and references for System.Data.SqlClient (MSSQL provider), uninstalled EntityFramework for MSSQLCE nuget package. Everything in the branch project works fine except two things: Add-Migration and Database seed script fail with the next error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: (0,0) : error 0175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded
```

I've tried to find the source of the issue and finally found that EDMX schema, which is stored in the __MigrationHistory of the MSSQL project database, contains the next line:

```
<Schema Namespace="CodeFirstDatabaseSchema" Provider="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" ProviderManifestToken="4.0" Alias="Self" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
```

But I don't understand, why it is generated with the Provider="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" option ? I've checked that my branch project doesn't have any file, which contains SqlServerCe substring (did file search in OS). I've tried to reinstall EntityFramework NuGet package, doesn't help as well.

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AnalyticDB;Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

EF version: 6.1.2

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run migrations against the databse before removein SQL CE references. You will have to nuke the _MigrationHistory table.

Comment: Thanks for answer Erik, unfortunately it doesn't help. I did it many times after removing links to CE (revert database to the 0 migration, then update it again), the wrong provider is still there. Is there any way to trace the building EDMX schema process ?

Comment: Did you try to remove the migrations - feel free to share a repro project if possible (email me via my blog)

Comment: Finally I found the solution: EF Migrations contain db model with connection reference in their resources files, so if you create migration for one DB server (MsSql CE in my case), you cannot apply them for another DB. I recreated them for my branch project and everything is fine now

Comment: Had the same issue with Code First: in one project I'm using Sqlite, in second Sql CE. I started with Sqlite. When I tried to apply the migration on Sql CE it showed me that "System.Data.SQLite.EF6" was missing - which strange because that project doesn't contain any references to Sqlite.